# C# Updating excel database and inserting record while adding items

Tags: c#, oledb

so I have this program which when I press a button inserts a record into an excel spreadsheet with, the columns, being , customer, product, weight, dateTime. Now I want to be able to update a record if the same customer, and product occurs, but I also want to add the previous weight field with the new field, and update the time.

The problem is i'm not sure how to modify my update statement to do this.

// Load data from database, and Update database if filed already exists

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string insertquery = "SELECT * FROM  [Sheet1$] where [Customer] = '" + lblcustomername + " ' ";
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(OutputDatabaseConnectionString); //define new connection object 
        OleDbDataAdapter mydataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertquery, myConnection); //define data adaptor and select column data from spreadsheet

        mydataadapter.Fill(ds);
        int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        // If item exists in database, update it
        if (i > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection2; //create new connection object
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                String sql = null;
                myConnection2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(OutputDatabaseConnectionString); //define connection string 
                myConnection2.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection2;
                sql = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Net Weight(Kg)]= '" + textBox1.Text + "' WHERE [Customer] = '" + lblcustomername + "'";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection2.Close();
                myConnection2.Close(); //close connection 
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        // if it doesn't exist update database
        try
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection1; //create new connection object
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            String sql = null;
            myConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(OutputDatabaseConnectionString); //define connection string 
            myConnection1.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection1;
            sql = sql = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Customer],[Product],[Net Weight(Kg)], [DateTime]) VALUES('" + lblcustomername.Text + "','" + lblproductname.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + (DateTime.Now).ToString() + "')";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection1.Close();
            myConnection1.Close(); //close connection 
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Much easier to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). Try it first, then you repost your question if you'd still have a problem.

Comment: Excel is not a database, I would use a free database like sql express integrated into your app to do the data manipulation and then export to excel. If you need to, you can import the spreadsheet first before you update.